# Kindly confirm the following SQL statement

Tags: mysql, join

I am looking at a MySQL statement with something like the following.

```
SELECT USER.foo_column ....
FROM FRIEND 
  JOIN USER ON USER.ID = FRIEND.USER_ID
    LEFT JOIN PROFILE ON PROFILE.USER_ID = USER.ID
     LEFT JOIN CAREER ON CAREER.USER_ID = USER.ID
...
```

I understand that the first join is an inner join between user and friend. That is then left joined with profile... however, can someone elaborate that in more detail? I mean do we decide whether the table is on the left or right depending on the order provided in the `ON`? So for `LEFT JOIN PROFILE ON PROFILE.USER_ID = USER.ID` (the first `LEFT JOIN`), is profile the table on the left and user on the right? And so the order would be reversed simply by making it `... ON USER.ID = PROFILE.USER_ID`? Or is it that the resulting table of the first join (inner) is on the left and then the profile on the right? If that is true, it would make career (after the last `LEFT JOIN`) the table on the furthest right?

Comment: *"do we decide whether the table is on the left or right depending on the order provided in the `ON`"* <- no. The left-ness of the join is specified by the table name immediately following the word `JOIN`

Comment: I am confused. Are you saying that the table name specified immediately after the `LEFT JOIN` is the table on the left and the resulting table from the first join is on the right? If so, can you explain the following? From what I can tell, they seem to say exactly the opposite. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: Okay, thank you for pointing out that the "left-ness" is not determined by what's after `ON`... however, it seems that the "left-ness" is determined by the table immediately PRECEDING the `LEFT JOIN` not following it.